# SQL multiple tables join problem with SUM Results Multiples times Higher Value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sum

I want to join these 4 tables

- tblretailer
- tbldraw
- Tbl_ABC
- Tbl_ABACBC

`'tblretailer '` is the main table. Sample data from `'tblratailer'` looks like this:

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
| ID |        Name         |    Place    |   Phone    | StraightRate | BoxRate | AbcRate | AbRate | CreatedDate |
+----+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
|  3 | Zen Commmunications | Navi mumbai | 3456728102 |            8 |       8 |    8.50 |      7 | 2020-05-02  |
|  4 | ASpire Systems      | New Delhi   | 4324535453 |         8.50 |    8.50 |       9 |      8 | 2020-05-02  |
|  5 | excel Systems       | New Delhi   | 4324535453 |         8.50 |    8.50 |       9 |      8 | 2020-05-02  |
+----+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+--------+-------------+
```

Sample data for `tbldraw`

```
+------+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+----------+
|  ID  | RetailerID | DrawNumberr | Count | CreatedDate | BoxCount |
+------+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+----------+
| 2368 |          4 |         123 |    10 | 2020-06-01  |       20 |
| 2370 |          4 |         777 |    15 | 2020-06-01  |       18 |
| 2371 |          3 |         153 |   100 | 2020-06-01  |       20 |
| 2372 |          3 |         758 |    50 | 2020-06-01  |       20 |
| 2374 |          3 |         777 |    10 | 2020-06-01  |        5 |
+------+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+----------+
```

Sample data for `Tbl_ABC`

```
+----+------------+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| ID | RetailerID | ANum | BNum | CNum | ACount | BCount | CCount | CreatedDate |
+----+------------+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| 21 |          4 |    1 | 2    | 3    |     10 |      5 |     15 | 2020-06-01  |
| 22 |          4 |    3 | 2    | 3    |     10 |     20 |     15 | 2020-06-01  |
| 23 |          3 |    2 | 6    | NULL |     10 |     25 |      0 | 2020-06-01  |
| 24 |          3 |    1 | NULL | NULL |     80 |      0 |      0 | 2020-06-01  |
| 25 |          3 |    4 | 5    | 8    |     10 |      5 |     20 | 2020-06-01  |
+----+------------+------+------+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Sample data for `Tbl_ABACBC`

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
| ID | RetailerID | ABNum | ACNum | BCNum | ABCount | ACCount | BCCount | CreatedDate |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
|  9 |          4 |    12 |    20 |    30 |      10 |      10 |      10 | 2020-06-01  |
| 10 |          4 |    55 |    23 |    26 |      15 |      15 |      15 | 2020-06-01  |
| 11 |          3 |    12 |    89 |     0 |      15 |      20 |       0 | 2020-06-01  |
| 12 |          3 |     0 |    20 |    25 |       0 |      10 |      20 | 2020-06-01  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+
```

and my SQL Server Stored Procedure code is given below

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2020-06-01' 

--  SELECT * FROM tblDraw  
SELECT 
    RETAILER.id, 
    NAME AS retailername, 
    SUM(ISNULL(acount, 0)) AS atotal, 
    SUM(ISNULL(bcount, 0)) AS Btotal, 
    SUM(ISNULL(ccount, 0)) AS Ctotal, 
    SUM(ISNULL(count, 0)) AS strtotal, 
    SUM(ISNULL(boxcount, 0)) AS boxtotal, 
    SUM(ISNULL(abcount, 0)) AS abtotal, 
    SUM(ISNULL(account, 0)) AS actotal, 
    SUM(ISNULL(bccount, 0)) AS bctotal 
FROM   
    tblretailer RETAILER 
RIGHT JOIN 
    tbl_abc ABC ON ABC.retailerid = RETAILER.id 
RIGHT JOIN 
    tbldraw DRAW ON DRAW.retailerid = RETAILER.id 
RIGHT JOIN 
    tbl_abacbc ABACBC ON ABACBC.retailerid = RETAILER.id 
WHERE  
    (ISNULL(ABC.createddate, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) = @Date 
     OR ISNULL(DRAW.createddate, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) = @Date 
     OR ISNULL(ABACBC.createddate, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) = @Date) 
GROUP BY 
    RETAILER.id, RETAILER.NAME, RETAILER.straightrate, 
    RETAILER.boxrate, RETAILER.abcrate, RETAILER.abrate
```

But the results are wrong with this code and not producing the expected result. It counts 4 times higher - I think there is a problem with join.

`Result` is

```
    +----+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
    | ID |    retailername     | atotal | btotal | ctotal | strtotal | boxtotal | abtotal | actotal | bctotal |
    +----+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
    |  3 | Zen Commmunications |    360 |    100 |    0   |      600 |      160 |     135 |     120 |     80  |
    |  4 | ASpire Systems      |     80 |    100 |    120 |      100 |      152 |     100 |     100 |     100 |
    +----+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The expected result is

```
+----+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| ID |    retailername    | atotal | btotal | ctotal |  strtotal | boxtotal | abtotal | actotal | bctotal | 
+----+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|  3 | Zen Communucations |     90 |     25 |      0 |       150 |       40 |      15 |      30 |      20 |
|  4 | Aspire Systems     |     20 |     25 |     30 |        25 |       38 |      25 |      25 |      25 |  
+----+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: I get that a retailer can have multiple draws on the same day but I don't get how draws relate to tblabc and tblabcbc. Also left joins are the more usual approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Records count are differing each tables**, that's why value increasing due to **duplication of records**, to avoid this take **sum before joining a tables**,. It will give better results and also your expected result also wrong for the sample data.

**Suggestion:** To better result you can replace *RIGHT OUTER JOIN* with *LEFT OUTER JOIN*.

Here is the code:

```
--------Table Creation Part-----
CREATE TABLE #tblretailer
(
ID INT,
[NAME] VARCHAR(50),
PLACE VARCHAR(25),
PHONE VARCHAR(10),
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #tbldraw
(
ID INT,
RetailerID  INT,
DrawNumber INT,
[Count] INT,
CreatedDate DATE
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #Tbl_ABC
(
ID INT,
RetailerID  INT,
ANum INT,
BNum INT,
CNum INT,
ACount INT,
BCount INT,
CCount INT,
CreatedDate DATE
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #Tbl_ABACBC
(
ID INT,
RetailerID  INT,
ANum INT,
BNum INT,
CNum INT,
ABCount INT,
ACCount INT,
BCCount INT,
CreatedDate DATE
)
GO

/*
DROP TABLE #tblretailer, #tbldraw, #Tbl_ABC, #Tbl_ABACBC
GO
*/
-----Value Insert-------
INSERT INTO #tblretailer
SELECT 3, 'Zen Commmunications','Navi mumbai','3456728102'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'ASpire Systems','New Delhi','4324535453'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Zen Commmunications','New Delhi','4324535454'
GO

INSERT INTO #tbldraw
SELECT 2368, 4, 123, 10, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2370, 4, 777, 15, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2371, 3, 153, 100, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2372, 3, 758, 50, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2374, 3, 777, 10, '2020-06-01'
GO

INSERT INTO #Tbl_ABC
SELECT 21, 4, 1, 2, 3, 10, 5, 15, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 22, 4, 1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 15, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 23, 3, 1, 2, 3, 10, 25, 0, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 24, 3, 1, 2, 3, 80, 0, 0, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 25, 3, 1, 2, 3, 10, 5, 20, '2020-06-01'
GO

INSERT INTO #Tbl_ABACBC
SELECT 9, 4, 12, 20, 30, 10, 10, 10, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 4, 12, 20, 30, 15, 15, 15, '2020-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 3, 12, 20, 30, 15, 20, 0, '2020-06-01'   
UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 3, 12, 20, 30, 0, 10, 20, '2020-06-01'
GO

----Query Part-----
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2020-06-01' 

SELECT 
    RETAILER.id, 
    NAME AS retailername, 
    atotal, 
    Btotal, 
    Ctotal, 
    strtotal, 
   -- SUM(ISNULL(boxcount, 0)) AS boxtotal, 
    abtotal, 
    actotal, 
    bctotal 
FROM   
    #tblretailer AS RETAILER 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
            ABC.retailerid
            , SUM(ISNULL(acount, 0)) AS atotal
            , SUM(ISNULL(bcount, 0)) AS Btotal
            , SUM(ISNULL(ccount, 0)) AS Ctotal 
    FROM 
            #tbl_abc  AS ABC
    WHERE
            ISNULL(ABC.createddate, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) = @Date 
    GROUP BY
            ABC.retailerid
     ) AS ABC ON ABC.retailerid = RETAILER.id 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
            DRAW.retailerid
            --, SUM(ISNULL(boxcount, 0)) AS boxtotal
            , SUM(ISNULL(count, 0)) AS strtotal
    FROM 
            #tbldraw  AS DRAW
    WHERE 
            ISNULL(DRAW.createddate, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) = @Date 
    GROUP BY
            DRAW.retailerid
    ) AS DR ON DR.retailerid = RETAILER.id 
RIGHT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
            ABACBC.retailerid
            , SUM(ISNULL(abcount, 0)) AS abtotal
            , SUM(ISNULL(account, 0)) AS actotal
            , SUM(ISNULL(bccount, 0)) AS bctotal
    FROM 
            #tbl_abacbc  AS ABACBC
    WHERE 
            ISNULL(ABACBC.createddate, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) = @Date
    GROUP BY
            ABACBC.retailerid
     ) AS ABACBC ON ABACBC.retailerid = RETAILER.id 
--GROUP BY 
--    RETAILER.id, RETAILER.NAME , RETAILER.straightrate, RETAILER.boxrate, RETAILER.abcrate, RETAILER.abrate
```

Result :

```
id  retailername    atotal  Btotal  Ctotal  strtotal    abtotal actotal bctotal
1   3   Zen Commmunications 100 30  20  160 15  30  20
2   4   ASpire Systems  20  25  30  25  25  25  25
```